# jQuery toggle - Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: jquery, get, show-hide

i try to show one element of a class with this jquery code:

```
jQuery('.slide_cover').get(0).toggle(800);
```

but i get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

and code lick this works fine:

```
jQuery('.slide_cover').toggle(800);
```

also if i try to get the element in console so it works

```
jQuery('.slide_cover').get(0)
```

Can you help me?
Thank you!

Comment: You can try like `jQuery('.slide_cover').eq(0).toggle(800);` OR `$('.slide_cover:eq(0)').toggle(800);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using `get()`, jQuery returns the native (underlying) DOM object from the array of elements in context and that `HTMLElement` doesn't provide the `toggle()` method.

If you want to call `toggle` only on the first element in context, try this:

```
jQuery('.slide_cover:first').toggle(800);
```

See [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/get/)

Comment: Oh okay! But i would only display one Element of the classes... how can i do this?

Comment: Okay, and the second element of class?

Comment: I am also getting the same error when I use toggle like this  var anim = "slide";
            var duration = 500;
            var options = { direction: 'left' };
            $("#cbp-spmenu-s1").toggle(anim, options, duration);